# How to create progress bars?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a waveform with progress bars that fill with another color from left to right. 
Right now it looks:

[image: right now]

I want it to look like this. Yellow is buffered audio, orange is playing right now.  I already have these values.

[image: wanna do]

The main question is how do I fill each `rect` with color by currentTime of audio?

Here's my code:

```js
const elementWidth = 1100
const elementHeight = 64

const duration = 160
const currentTime = 20
const buffered = 140
// here's data that i get from web audio api
// bar length in seconds would be:
// duration / renderData = how much seconds in one bar

const renderData = [
  [-0.015067690176936956, 0.015065840696712662],
  [-0.009963374263646985, 0.009960838406137254],
  [-0.0329772714073922, 0.032922178973984494],
  [-0.02010780853750818, 0.020192897509204638],
  [-0.029141768346505944, 0.02913273608186522],
  [-0.03390369982419367, 0.033888949138664096],
  [-0.05309944789682607, 0.053106191954295334],
  [-0.017992382356680794, 0.0179506794436456],
  [-0.04118192967225779, 0.04120773269527067],
  [-0.032132343283569134, 0.03223372926977138],
  [-0.04340663941189386, 0.043317410948806916],
  [-0.026866048759920942, 0.02695383570549558],
  [-0.041548487297645216, 0.04142889765358134],
  [-0.0512541217270734, 0.05128097373670754],
  [-0.02645596673127562, 0.026461825339764114],
  [-0.03276659370022165, 0.032869462727325334],
  [-0.02983164709570332, 0.02965126735342542],
  [-0.06186988270590101, 0.06228762507639405],
  [-0.037202475771159274, 0.03684529067849468],
  [-0.04496168984286248, 0.044984343262096924],
  [-0.02961698097048877, 0.029580527280458145],
  [-0.06637895360455075, 0.06584970915134748],
  [-0.03966561332234608, 0.04028105442218536],
  [-0.04888827685580639, 0.04879637577182824],
  [-0.034440279218927505, 0.03448690299802526],
  [-0.04076603383847427, 0.04087949817166488],
  [-0.03422100968150345, 0.03407137586231854],
  [-0.03420552026962888, 0.034233479991186845],
  [-0.06124921943975816, 0.06133406711072517],
  [-0.08080063612343565, 0.08052139740352077],
  [-0.052296123826832304, 0.05245498821828788],
  [-0.07728568068325997, 0.0772439557897976],
  [-0.04070025960953707, 0.04072465208052425],
  [-0.016598400103531252, 0.01673240062886387],
  [-0.0495708419979178, 0.04952405213368158],
  [-0.03402468183819489, 0.03404496946468417],
  [-0.04719791564971553, 0.04716565090961255],
  [-0.024305039710776202, 0.024425998358774473],
  [-0.04539290174457686, 0.0453603392364138],
  [-0.04291280211166326, 0.042803252613569195],
  [-0.03237617188947045, 0.032430479168267405],
  [-0.046939414609483046, 0.046991124408919255],
  [-0.037727014544829074, 0.03756628029896137],
  [-0.05813820211592722, 0.058137499737658825],
  [-0.03306609736616569, 0.03332803022833292],
  [-0.03706343131822335, 0.03699838219166897],
  [-0.031640843865570666, 0.03150685332686255],
  [-0.07978720110560034, 0.07982405111308474],
  [-0.04565408283291298, 0.04548542047551325],
  [-0.03838929844552628, 0.0386080775422541],
  [-0.0349069030273341, 0.03516624962570975],
  [-0.05791808093217102, 0.057646960595115364],
  [-0.040111244425499945, 0.040190047578908046],
  [-0.0421531094659709, 0.04210734133509555],
  [-0.04358563889018587, 0.043380678911277275],
  [-0.024025454017633886, 0.024179111399202893],
  [-0.039038574013751944, 0.03889745017750074],
  [-0.02962543563292595, 0.02975662299643922],
  [-0.07215596460653108, 0.07225534620830149],
  [-0.0845103969948925, 0.08417566858032748],
  [-0.05029865141667644, 0.05110349428845409],
  [-0.06766253837563593, 0.06680008803627584],
  [-0.05413748268128195, 0.054261121431710246],
  [-0.04702217202288801, 0.04710783667779247],
  [-0.047177278676382065, 0.047241381909344966],
  [-0.04949906253183499, 0.049358880485210296],
  [-0.06384145451618915, 0.06398437795989458],
  [-0.0532812223855561, 0.05336013656088595],
  [-0.055032831282645335, 0.055131815418379866],
  [-0.05771727930777607, 0.05743980672281111],
  [-0.06865421948220482, 0.06896493506959074],
  [-0.05163944571854085, 0.05129081551014095],
  [-0.04546664828758613, 0.04549366890782257],
  [-0.02196073923070452, 0.022119579288034315],
  [-0.026824862238895183, 0.026915318981447094],
  [-0.04771898452983383, 0.04768769589918763],
  [-0.05221904154341058, 0.05202229643239835],
  [-0.04034726803191834, 0.040288317010035164],
  [-0.04252634158686052, 0.04275796625513488],
  [-0.055381424446109724, 0.05515857756430962],
  [-0.06160043085044191, 0.06143890271068376],
  [-0.04579617210990365, 0.04612433751815954],
  [-0.039244869887493206, 0.03927668403684328],
  [-0.03426885260996771, 0.03423936180141113],
  [-0.03516869910983574, 0.035127711830890515],
  [-0.026964357386084752, 0.02699723933039285],
  [-0.03816966714682839, 0.03778890745758835],
  [-0.04777519168041681, 0.04824239079542675],
  [-0.07617805358108933, 0.07612545525147858],
  [-0.047140552370394925, 0.04744151736320112],
  [-0.05137018378775051, 0.051114804207469784],
  [-0.03259493948312707, 0.0325308332802452],
  [-0.05715909221362399, 0.05709963073119724],
  [-0.04835633252739353, 0.04849600527981289],
  [-0.0433886628912617, 0.04331087342221564],
  [-0.05191740499328957, 0.05183144200010501],
  [-0.022690824730811025, 0.02281282548488598],
  [-0.021657892287654815, 0.02160585204290785],
  [-0.019911292276869504, 0.01990373441321122],
  [-0.05252214322669061, 0.052514338488489534],
  [-0.045757900781809524, 0.04581189437809006],
  [-0.02396372548560904, 0.023788207356191405],
  [-0.053426097224355276, 0.05348064888976746],
  [-0.05394891160261981, 0.05421456735805457],
  [-0.05251658416178273, 0.05238904616093791],
  [-0.04774168806444406, 0.047755594530669916],
  [-0.03506924339896615, 0.035076784816174336],
  [-0.044288649573623336, 0.044337743067559894],
  [-0.05109649028135573, 0.050986769978167874],
  [-0.03986396401411081, 0.03992226520835857],
  [-0.06271544843396921, 0.0628629998182233],
  [-0.060325113831802425, 0.06014867491287253],
  [-0.06409607265208252, 0.06426716029136537],
  [-0.02890807357828784, 0.02879981209701445],
  [-0.0579076968762734, 0.058055472378755635],
  [-0.0788244096514242, 0.07889209396389751],
  [-0.05489594835332056, 0.054304463238473114],
  [-0.05066376350430718, 0.051136225666937284],
  [-0.04324084422009672, 0.043106921303429975],
  [-0.03618639085199314, 0.03630391952984575],
  [-0.03229893887218463, 0.032254130211298596],
  [-0.040388961018727465, 0.04034166483632292],
  [-0.06891322548088202, 0.06894551548689337],
  [-0.05708462516274434, 0.05713687370165375],
  [-0.0908320094478539, 0.09053809343169553],
  [-0.06997210675874246, 0.07036387396569341],
  [-0.027676689451677956, 0.02757377175784071],
  [-0.02882633060378825, 0.029207481257562274],
  [-0.0414701765332311, 0.04136630655327525],
  [-0.05308296364144847, 0.0526747543606357],
  [-0.02724146501450132, 0.027406581699254588],
  [-0.04265844625269343, 0.04270290902986972],
  [-0.03899306746018118, 0.038745252551468795],
  [-0.0552804734553083, 0.05535944558193926],
  [-0.02309096284644189, 0.023040044134232315],
  [-0.0507964500028555, 0.05096013747702334],
  [-0.04123972706510699, 0.041359046982264745],
  [-0.03236153261658939, 0.032179960855430505],
  [-0.02858521671477931, 0.028570736354436077],
  [-0.03515761112679279, 0.03513507691850391],
  [-0.049852204843317816, 0.04984858000374448],
  [-0.038280519845162314, 0.038365751907998916],
  [-0.05489151074836156, 0.054958999808454506],
  [-0.02552547302215947, 0.025555844960312334],
  [-0.06393766191228746, 0.0638978766928521],
  [-0.04140103340243134, 0.04113465467714282],
  [-0.04647459357809104, 0.04654619117779597],
  [-0.03293849813553063, 0.03301029011724379],
  [-0.04428244235309984, 0.04433992273438912],
  [-0.047489538949244604, 0.04755256034371833],
  [-0.047176763166566854, 0.04719291045558167],
  [-0.06353201748860114, 0.06380784207550017],
  [-0.07775209195691819, 0.0773872824070752],
  [-0.054300174262817344, 0.054476381979975085],
  [-0.08808678703605805, 0.0879414485377677],
  [-0.04016286323725983, 0.04007725752721749],
  [-0.01889086923709467, 0.018989486049242103]
]

const height = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(renderData.map(e => e[1] - e[0])))
  .range([0, elementHeight])

d3.select(document.getElementById('app'))
  .append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'd3')
  .attr('width', elementWidth)
  .attr('height', elementHeight)
  .selectAll('.bar')
  .data(renderData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bar')
  .attr('fill', '#E0E0E0')
  .attr('x', (d, i) => (i * 2 + i))
  .attr('y', d => elementHeight - height(d[1] - d[0]))
  .transition()
  .duration(300)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr('width', 2)
  .attr('height', d => height(d[1] - d[0]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the structure of `renderData` and how do you determine the thresholds?

Comment: it's like soundcloud

Comment: @altocumulus renderData: [ [number, number], [number, number] ...  ] and about thresholds I didn't think. I got from audio duration and current time. Width is 1100 pixels, so I can get width of current time.

Comment: Hmm, since you mention buffered audio and orange is playing now, can't you change the color of the previous yellow bar to orange when the next buffered chuck starts? If it has to be by currentTime, you'll have to do some calculations to see how many seconds have to pass for the next bar to become orange, which will be more annoying to make than if you could listen to like `buffer.onchunk()` ( not real code ) or something.

Comment: @Shilly i'm not very familiar with d3. I think i can calculate how much time is one bar  and fill it somehow. Is it possible to fill e.g. half bar? Or it will have to be new bar sitting on old bar?

Comment: You can, but what do you exactly mean? Every yellow bar should have its own rect element, so don't you want to make the entire rect element orange? or do you like need vertical coloring? Like 'the current active bar is orange with a blue tip on top' or something? If you post a samle renderData array, we can test the code to see what you mean exactly.

Comment: @Shilly [here's sample](https://gist.github.com/chrisands/55a1bddcef173ce0aa8ef319fe378218). Every bar is separate rect. I thought e.g. bar is 1 second of time and how to show 0.5 second, but that probably with transition possible to do.

Comment: Hmm, I understand now. There's no easy fix for this that i know.of unless WaveformD3 has one. Closest I can think of atm is using a gradient to have a bar with a orange side on the left and a yellow side on the right.

Comment: @Shilly WaveformD3 is object with d3 functions for React injection purposes :) Gradient is good idea, but I'll later will something figure out if it is hard to implement.

Comment: have you looked into the https://wavesurfer-js.org/

Comment: Are you able to add a MCVE to your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, i did. It doesn't worked for me.

Comment: @ksav added example to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some simple logic in `function paint()` to determine the fill color. Then you need need to decide how often to re-render (I guess at least once every second for updating `currentTime`).

```js
const elementWidth = 1100;
const elementHeight = 64;

const duration = 160;
let currentTime = 0;
const buffered = 140;

const renderData = [[-0.015067690176936956, 0.015065840696712662],[-0.009963374263646985, 0.009960838406137254],[-0.0329772714073922, 0.032922178973984494],[-0.02010780853750818, 0.020192897509204638],[-0.029141768346505944, 0.02913273608186522],[-0.03390369982419367, 0.033888949138664096],[-0.05309944789682607, 0.053106191954295334],[-0.017992382356680794, 0.0179506794436456],[-0.04118192967225779, 0.04120773269527067],[-0.032132343283569134, 0.03223372926977138],[-0.04340663941189386, 0.043317410948806916],[-0.026866048759920942, 0.02695383570549558],[-0.041548487297645216, 0.04142889765358134],[-0.0512541217270734, 0.05128097373670754],[-0.02645596673127562, 0.026461825339764114],[-0.03276659370022165, 0.032869462727325334],[-0.02983164709570332, 0.02965126735342542],[-0.06186988270590101, 0.06228762507639405],[-0.037202475771159274, 0.03684529067849468],[-0.04496168984286248, 0.044984343262096924],[-0.02961698097048877, 0.029580527280458145],[-0.06637895360455075, 0.06584970915134748],[-0.03966561332234608, 0.04028105442218536],[-0.04888827685580639, 0.04879637577182824],[-0.034440279218927505, 0.03448690299802526],[-0.04076603383847427, 0.04087949817166488],[-0.03422100968150345, 0.03407137586231854],[-0.03420552026962888, 0.034233479991186845],[-0.06124921943975816, 0.06133406711072517],[-0.08080063612343565, 0.08052139740352077],[-0.052296123826832304, 0.05245498821828788],[-0.07728568068325997, 0.0772439557897976],[-0.04070025960953707, 0.04072465208052425],[-0.016598400103531252, 0.01673240062886387],[-0.0495708419979178, 0.04952405213368158],[-0.03402468183819489, 0.03404496946468417],[-0.04719791564971553, 0.04716565090961255],[-0.024305039710776202, 0.024425998358774473],[-0.04539290174457686, 0.0453603392364138],[-0.04291280211166326, 0.042803252613569195],[-0.03237617188947045, 0.032430479168267405],[-0.046939414609483046, 0.046991124408919255],[-0.037727014544829074, 0.03756628029896137],[-0.05813820211592722, 0.058137499737658825],[-0.03306609736616569, 0.03332803022833292],[-0.03706343131822335, 0.03699838219166897],[-0.031640843865570666, 0.03150685332686255],[-0.07978720110560034, 0.07982405111308474],[-0.04565408283291298, 0.04548542047551325],[-0.03838929844552628, 0.0386080775422541],[-0.0349069030273341, 0.03516624962570975],[-0.05791808093217102, 0.057646960595115364],[-0.040111244425499945, 0.040190047578908046],[-0.0421531094659709, 0.04210734133509555],[-0.04358563889018587, 0.043380678911277275],[-0.024025454017633886, 0.024179111399202893],[-0.039038574013751944, 0.03889745017750074],[-0.02962543563292595, 0.02975662299643922],[-0.07215596460653108, 0.07225534620830149],[-0.0845103969948925, 0.08417566858032748],[-0.05029865141667644, 0.05110349428845409],[-0.06766253837563593, 0.06680008803627584],[-0.05413748268128195, 0.054261121431710246],[-0.04702217202288801, 0.04710783667779247],[-0.047177278676382065, 0.047241381909344966],[-0.04949906253183499, 0.049358880485210296],[-0.06384145451618915, 0.06398437795989458],[-0.0532812223855561, 0.05336013656088595],[-0.055032831282645335, 0.055131815418379866],[-0.05771727930777607, 0.05743980672281111],[-0.06865421948220482, 0.06896493506959074],[-0.05163944571854085, 0.05129081551014095],[-0.04546664828758613, 0.04549366890782257],[-0.02196073923070452, 0.022119579288034315],[-0.026824862238895183, 0.026915318981447094],[-0.04771898452983383, 0.04768769589918763],[-0.05221904154341058, 0.05202229643239835],[-0.04034726803191834, 0.040288317010035164],[-0.04252634158686052, 0.04275796625513488],[-0.055381424446109724, 0.05515857756430962],[-0.06160043085044191, 0.06143890271068376],[-0.04579617210990365, 0.04612433751815954],[-0.039244869887493206, 0.03927668403684328],[-0.03426885260996771, 0.03423936180141113],[-0.03516869910983574, 0.035127711830890515],[-0.026964357386084752, 0.02699723933039285],[-0.03816966714682839, 0.03778890745758835],[-0.04777519168041681, 0.04824239079542675],[-0.07617805358108933, 0.07612545525147858],[-0.047140552370394925, 0.04744151736320112],[-0.05137018378775051, 0.051114804207469784],[-0.03259493948312707, 0.0325308332802452],[-0.05715909221362399, 0.05709963073119724],[-0.04835633252739353, 0.04849600527981289],[-0.0433886628912617, 0.04331087342221564],[-0.05191740499328957, 0.05183144200010501],[-0.022690824730811025, 0.02281282548488598],[-0.021657892287654815, 0.02160585204290785],[-0.019911292276869504, 0.01990373441321122],[-0.05252214322669061, 0.052514338488489534],[-0.045757900781809524, 0.04581189437809006],[-0.02396372548560904, 0.023788207356191405],[-0.053426097224355276, 0.05348064888976746],[-0.05394891160261981, 0.05421456735805457],[-0.05251658416178273, 0.05238904616093791],[-0.04774168806444406, 0.047755594530669916],[-0.03506924339896615, 0.035076784816174336],[-0.044288649573623336, 0.044337743067559894],[-0.05109649028135573, 0.050986769978167874],[-0.03986396401411081, 0.03992226520835857],[-0.06271544843396921, 0.0628629998182233],[-0.060325113831802425, 0.06014867491287253],[-0.06409607265208252, 0.06426716029136537],[-0.02890807357828784, 0.02879981209701445],[-0.0579076968762734, 0.058055472378755635],[-0.0788244096514242, 0.07889209396389751],[-0.05489594835332056, 0.054304463238473114],[-0.05066376350430718, 0.051136225666937284],[-0.04324084422009672, 0.043106921303429975],[-0.03618639085199314, 0.03630391952984575],[-0.03229893887218463, 0.032254130211298596],[-0.040388961018727465, 0.04034166483632292],[-0.06891322548088202, 0.06894551548689337],[-0.05708462516274434, 0.05713687370165375],[-0.0908320094478539, 0.09053809343169553],[-0.06997210675874246, 0.07036387396569341],[-0.027676689451677956, 0.02757377175784071],[-0.02882633060378825, 0.029207481257562274],[-0.0414701765332311, 0.04136630655327525],[-0.05308296364144847, 0.0526747543606357],[-0.02724146501450132, 0.027406581699254588],[-0.04265844625269343, 0.04270290902986972],[-0.03899306746018118, 0.038745252551468795],[-0.0552804734553083, 0.05535944558193926],[-0.02309096284644189, 0.023040044134232315],[-0.0507964500028555, 0.05096013747702334],[-0.04123972706510699, 0.041359046982264745],[-0.03236153261658939, 0.032179960855430505],[-0.02858521671477931, 0.028570736354436077],[-0.03515761112679279, 0.03513507691850391],[-0.049852204843317816, 0.04984858000374448],[-0.038280519845162314, 0.038365751907998916],[-0.05489151074836156, 0.054958999808454506],[-0.02552547302215947, 0.025555844960312334],[-0.06393766191228746, 0.0638978766928521],[-0.04140103340243134, 0.04113465467714282],[-0.04647459357809104, 0.04654619117779597],[-0.03293849813553063, 0.03301029011724379],[-0.04428244235309984, 0.04433992273438912],[-0.047489538949244604, 0.04755256034371833],[-0.047176763166566854, 0.04719291045558167],[-0.06353201748860114, 0.06380784207550017],[-0.07775209195691819, 0.0773872824070752],[-0.054300174262817344, 0.054476381979975085],[-0.08808678703605805, 0.0879414485377677],[-0.04016286323725983, 0.04007725752721749],[-0.01889086923709467, 0.018989486049242103]];

const height = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(renderData.map(e => e[1] - e[0])))
  .range([0, elementHeight]);

const svg = d3
  .select("#app")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "d3")
  .attr("width", elementWidth)
  .attr("height", elementHeight);

const bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(renderData);

const barEnter = bar
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => {
    return paint(i);
  })
  .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 2 + i)
  .attr("y", d => elementHeight - height(d[1] - d[0]))
  .attr("width", 2)
  .attr("height", d => height(d[1] - d[0]));

function reRender() {
  currentTime += 1
  barEnter.attr("fill", (d, i) => {
    return paint(i);
  })
}

window.setInterval(function () {
  reRender()
}, 1000);

function paint(i) {
  barPos = i / renderData.length * duration;
  if (barPos <= currentTime) {
    return "red";
  } else if (barPos <= buffered) {
    return "orange";
  } else {
    return "grey";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='app' />
</body>

</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/ebqdva)

Comment: I think barPos should be `i * (duration / renderData.length)`

Comment: Thank you! 
I optimized my code with your example! 
Still looking how to create on rect fill animation from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Its really fun to play with svg :)
This is what i made, have a look.

```js
const elementWidth = 1100
const elementHeight = 64
var audioTotalTime = 120.0000; // in secound
var currentTime = 0; 
var currentBuffer = 0;

const renderData = [
  [-0.015067690176936956, 0.015065840696712662],
  [-0.009963374263646985, 0.009960838406137254],
  [-0.0329772714073922, 0.032922178973984494],
  [-0.02010780853750818, 0.020192897509204638],
  [-0.029141768346505944, 0.02913273608186522],
  [-0.03390369982419367, 0.033888949138664096],
  [-0.05309944789682607, 0.053106191954295334],
  [-0.017992382356680794, 0.0179506794436456],
  [-0.04118192967225779, 0.04120773269527067],
  [-0.032132343283569134, 0.03223372926977138],
  [-0.04340663941189386, 0.043317410948806916],
  [-0.026866048759920942, 0.02695383570549558],
  [-0.041548487297645216, 0.04142889765358134],
  [-0.0512541217270734, 0.05128097373670754],
  [-0.02645596673127562, 0.026461825339764114],
  [-0.03276659370022165, 0.032869462727325334],
  [-0.02983164709570332, 0.02965126735342542],
  [-0.06186988270590101, 0.06228762507639405],
  [-0.037202475771159274, 0.03684529067849468],
  [-0.04496168984286248, 0.044984343262096924],
  [-0.02961698097048877, 0.029580527280458145],
  [-0.06637895360455075, 0.06584970915134748],
  [-0.03966561332234608, 0.04028105442218536],
  [-0.04888827685580639, 0.04879637577182824],
  [-0.034440279218927505, 0.03448690299802526],
  [-0.04076603383847427, 0.04087949817166488],
  [-0.03422100968150345, 0.03407137586231854],
  [-0.03420552026962888, 0.034233479991186845],
  [-0.06124921943975816, 0.06133406711072517],
  [-0.08080063612343565, 0.08052139740352077],
  [-0.052296123826832304, 0.05245498821828788],
  [-0.07728568068325997, 0.0772439557897976],
  [-0.04070025960953707, 0.04072465208052425],
  [-0.016598400103531252, 0.01673240062886387],
  [-0.0495708419979178, 0.04952405213368158],
  [-0.03402468183819489, 0.03404496946468417],
  [-0.04719791564971553, 0.04716565090961255],
  [-0.024305039710776202, 0.024425998358774473],
  [-0.04539290174457686, 0.0453603392364138],
  [-0.04291280211166326, 0.042803252613569195],
  [-0.03237617188947045, 0.032430479168267405],
  [-0.046939414609483046, 0.046991124408919255],
  [-0.037727014544829074, 0.03756628029896137],
  [-0.05813820211592722, 0.058137499737658825],
  [-0.03306609736616569, 0.03332803022833292],
  [-0.03706343131822335, 0.03699838219166897],
  [-0.031640843865570666, 0.03150685332686255],
  [-0.07978720110560034, 0.07982405111308474],
  [-0.04565408283291298, 0.04548542047551325],
  [-0.03838929844552628, 0.0386080775422541],
  [-0.0349069030273341, 0.03516624962570975],
  [-0.05791808093217102, 0.057646960595115364],
  [-0.040111244425499945, 0.040190047578908046],
  [-0.0421531094659709, 0.04210734133509555],
  [-0.04358563889018587, 0.043380678911277275],
  [-0.024025454017633886, 0.024179111399202893],
  [-0.039038574013751944, 0.03889745017750074],
  [-0.02962543563292595, 0.02975662299643922],
  [-0.07215596460653108, 0.07225534620830149],
  [-0.0845103969948925, 0.08417566858032748],
  [-0.05029865141667644, 0.05110349428845409],
  [-0.06766253837563593, 0.06680008803627584],
  [-0.05413748268128195, 0.054261121431710246],
  [-0.04702217202288801, 0.04710783667779247],
  [-0.047177278676382065, 0.047241381909344966],
  [-0.04949906253183499, 0.049358880485210296],
  [-0.06384145451618915, 0.06398437795989458],
  [-0.0532812223855561, 0.05336013656088595],
  [-0.055032831282645335, 0.055131815418379866],
  [-0.05771727930777607, 0.05743980672281111],
  [-0.06865421948220482, 0.06896493506959074],
  [-0.05163944571854085, 0.05129081551014095],
  [-0.04546664828758613, 0.04549366890782257],
  [-0.02196073923070452, 0.022119579288034315],
  [-0.026824862238895183, 0.026915318981447094],
  [-0.04771898452983383, 0.04768769589918763],
  [-0.05221904154341058, 0.05202229643239835],
  [-0.04034726803191834, 0.040288317010035164],
  [-0.04252634158686052, 0.04275796625513488],
  [-0.055381424446109724, 0.05515857756430962],
  [-0.06160043085044191, 0.06143890271068376],
  [-0.04579617210990365, 0.04612433751815954],
  [-0.039244869887493206, 0.03927668403684328],
  [-0.03426885260996771, 0.03423936180141113],
  [-0.03516869910983574, 0.035127711830890515],
  [-0.026964357386084752, 0.02699723933039285],
  [-0.03816966714682839, 0.03778890745758835],
  [-0.04777519168041681, 0.04824239079542675],
  [-0.07617805358108933, 0.07612545525147858],
  [-0.047140552370394925, 0.04744151736320112],
  [-0.05137018378775051, 0.051114804207469784],
  [-0.03259493948312707, 0.0325308332802452],
  [-0.05715909221362399, 0.05709963073119724],
  [-0.04835633252739353, 0.04849600527981289],
  [-0.0433886628912617, 0.04331087342221564],
  [-0.05191740499328957, 0.05183144200010501],
  [-0.022690824730811025, 0.02281282548488598],
  [-0.021657892287654815, 0.02160585204290785],
  [-0.019911292276869504, 0.01990373441321122],
  [-0.05252214322669061, 0.052514338488489534],
  [-0.045757900781809524, 0.04581189437809006],
  [-0.02396372548560904, 0.023788207356191405],
  [-0.053426097224355276, 0.05348064888976746],
  [-0.05394891160261981, 0.05421456735805457],
  [-0.05251658416178273, 0.05238904616093791],
  [-0.04774168806444406, 0.047755594530669916],
  [-0.03506924339896615, 0.035076784816174336],
  [-0.044288649573623336, 0.044337743067559894],
  [-0.05109649028135573, 0.050986769978167874],
  [-0.03986396401411081, 0.03992226520835857],
  [-0.06271544843396921, 0.0628629998182233],
  [-0.060325113831802425, 0.06014867491287253],
  [-0.06409607265208252, 0.06426716029136537],
  [-0.02890807357828784, 0.02879981209701445],
  [-0.0579076968762734, 0.058055472378755635],
  [-0.0788244096514242, 0.07889209396389751],
  [-0.05489594835332056, 0.054304463238473114],
  [-0.05066376350430718, 0.051136225666937284],
  [-0.04324084422009672, 0.043106921303429975],
  [-0.03618639085199314, 0.03630391952984575],
  [-0.03229893887218463, 0.032254130211298596],
  [-0.040388961018727465, 0.04034166483632292],
  [-0.06891322548088202, 0.06894551548689337],
  [-0.05708462516274434, 0.05713687370165375],
  [-0.0908320094478539, 0.09053809343169553],
  [-0.06997210675874246, 0.07036387396569341],
  [-0.027676689451677956, 0.02757377175784071],
  [-0.02882633060378825, 0.029207481257562274],
  [-0.0414701765332311, 0.04136630655327525],
  [-0.05308296364144847, 0.0526747543606357],
  [-0.02724146501450132, 0.027406581699254588],
  [-0.04265844625269343, 0.04270290902986972],
  [-0.03899306746018118, 0.038745252551468795],
  [-0.0552804734553083, 0.05535944558193926],
  [-0.02309096284644189, 0.023040044134232315],
  [-0.0507964500028555, 0.05096013747702334],
  [-0.04123972706510699, 0.041359046982264745],
  [-0.03236153261658939, 0.032179960855430505],
  [-0.02858521671477931, 0.028570736354436077],
  [-0.03515761112679279, 0.03513507691850391],
  [-0.049852204843317816, 0.04984858000374448],
  [-0.038280519845162314, 0.038365751907998916],
  [-0.05489151074836156, 0.054958999808454506],
  [-0.02552547302215947, 0.025555844960312334],
  [-0.06393766191228746, 0.0638978766928521],
  [-0.04140103340243134, 0.04113465467714282],
  [-0.04647459357809104, 0.04654619117779597],
  [-0.03293849813553063, 0.03301029011724379],
  [-0.04428244235309984, 0.04433992273438912],
  [-0.047489538949244604, 0.04755256034371833],
  [-0.047176763166566854, 0.04719291045558167],
  [-0.06353201748860114, 0.06380784207550017],
  [-0.07775209195691819, 0.0773872824070752],
  [-0.054300174262817344, 0.054476381979975085],
  [-0.08808678703605805, 0.0879414485377677],
  [-0.04016286323725983, 0.04007725752721749],
  [-0.01889086923709467, 0.018989486049242103]
]

const height = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(renderData.map(e => e[1] - e[0])))
  .range([0, elementHeight])

d3.select(document.getElementById('app'))
  .append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'd3')
  .attr('width', elementWidth)
  .attr('height', elementHeight)
  .selectAll('.bar')
  .data(renderData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bar')
  .attr('fill', '#E0E0E0')
  .attr('x', (d, i) => (i * 2 + i))
  .attr('y', d => elementHeight - height(d[1] - d[0]))
  .transition()
  .duration(300)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr('width', 2)
  .attr('height', d => height(d[1] - d[0]))
  
  
  var svg = $(".d3");
  var lng = svg.find("rect").length;
  function update(){
   var selectedRect = Math.floor(((currentTime ) / ( lng )) * (audioTotalTime + 86)); 
   var selectedBufferRect = Math.floor(((currentBuffer ) / ( lng )) * (audioTotalTime + 86)); 
   // this is the best i could do, but you understand the ide

   var playingColor = "red";
   var bufferColor = "green";
   
   // buffer Progress
  $.each (svg.find("rect"), function(index, i){ // buffer
   if (index<= selectedBufferRect &&$(this).attr("fill") != playingColor )
       $(this).attr("fill", bufferColor);
   
   });
   
   // Playing Progress
   $.each (svg.find("rect"), function(index, i){ // Playing
   if (index<= selectedRect)
       $(this).attr("fill", playingColor);
   
   });

   
}
  
  function PlayingSimulator(){
   currentTime += 1
   currentBuffer +=3;
   if (currentTime>= audioTotalTime){
    update();
    return false;
   }
    update();
   setTimeout(PlayingSimulator, 60);
  }
  
  
  PlayingSimulator();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for example, but i would like to use ecma syntax (or d3 functions if possible) rather that jquery. 
I think i can figure out how to do it with your example's logic.